# How do I convert this to a prepared statement in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

So I have already converted most of my queries into prepared statements but I'm stumped on this one. All the examples I have found are for simple one-line queries but I have one that is a little complex and bases itself off other results.

To clarify, I don't know how to make this a prepared statement so I'm asking how you would do that. I might be overthinking it but it didn't work when I tried. Deleted my source code I attempted it at last night.

```
<?php
include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
include_once 'includes/functions.php';

$ten_id = $_GET['parent'];
$end_d = $_POST["end_d"];

$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT property_id FROM tenancy WHERE tent_id = '$ten_id' AND current = 1");
while($row = $results->fetch_array()) {
 $property = $row["property_id"];
}
$mysqli->query("
        UPDATE tenant SET current='0' WHERE id=' $ten_id';
        ");
$mysqli->query("
        UPDATE property SET occupied='0' WHERE id=' $property';
        ");
$mysqli->query("
        UPDATE tenancy SET current='0', end_date='$end_d' WHERE tent_id='$ten_id' AND current = 1;
        ");
?>
```

I'm not asking you to just convert this to prepared statements. If you do great but please explain how you got there. I don't understand how to write the first row then fetch it to get the id and then update the other 2 rows in other tables

Comment: Please remove the Run code snippet action, it's not HTML

Comment: how sorry I'm new here EDIT nvm i figured it out on that

Comment: the manual's a good start http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: OK I edited it hopefully I made my question clear. Although it's more of a statement that I just understand how it works. I'm self taught and haven't used PHP since 2010